# splitting a large column into equal no of lines in linux

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, awk, sed

i have a large column of file that contain 4005 lines(rows), i want to split it into 500 equal no of lines and want to paste it side by side in order to get a matrix like form.

I tried with `split` command but in my system split command is used by some other software, so it ask me `input file`

I tried `split --lines=500` it ask me input file

i tried `sed -n '1,500p' inputfile > output.txt` t does the work but manually i have to do many times

so i wonder if other solution is there other than split and sed for the same.

Comment: check `type split` and `man split` to make sure what `split` you got.

Comment: yes split is there in my system but it is used by different software when i type split on the terminal....something like split
  INPUT FILE NAME

Comment: yes when i type type split it gives path of that software

Comment: _Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers._ There are other sites in the [SE network](https://stackexchange.com/sites#technology) better suited for this kind of questions. Superuser sound like the place for this one.

Comment: ok this is my last question in this platform....after that i will jump there

Comment: `pr -t500 -s' ' file.txt`

Comment: 4005 is not divisible by 500. What do you mean by "split into equal number of lines" ?

Comment: [edit] your question to talk about and show an example of input that's 10 lines long and you want split into 3 equal number of lines rather than 4005 lines you want split into 500. That way we'll see what you want done when the input file doesn't actually split evenly and have something we can copy/paste to test a potential solution with.

Comment: It's not at all clear why you're surprised that `split` is asking you for the name of a file to operate on. You're providing the name of an input file to sed so why wouldn't you do the same for split? What is split supposed to do if it doesn't have input to work on?

Comment: @Jetchisel it's not entirely clear but it seems like the OP wants 500 lines per output column, not 500 output columns as they'd get from `pr -t500 -s' '`, since they said `sed -n '1,500p'` works and they tried `split --lines=500`.

Comment: @EdMorton, true that's why I did not post an answer just a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't clear, especially in regards to how to handle files that don't split evenly om the number of output lines you want, but it seems like this might be what you're trying to do:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    OFS = "\t"
    numRows = 3
}
(NR%numRows) == 1 {
    ++numCols
    rowNr = 0
}
{ vals[++rowNr,numCols] = $0 }
END {
    for (rowNr=1; rowNr<=numRows; rowNr++) {
        for (colNr=1; colNr<=numCols; colNr++) {
            printf "%s%s", vals[rowNr,colNr], (colNr<numCols ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }
}
```

```
$ seq 10 | awk -f tst.awk
1       4       7       10
2       5       8
3       6       9
```

Obviously change `numRows` from 3 to 500 for your real application.